# Storing gzipped data in redis

Tags: python, redis, tornado

I have a huge python dictionary that i want to save to redis cache and then have an API handler return this dictionary straight from cache

Im using `gzip` to compress the stringified dict first before storing in cache

```
 transformed_object = {...big dictionary}

    byte_object = BytesIO()

    data = json.dumps(transformed_object)
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=byte_object, mode="w") as f:
        f.write(data.encode())

    final_data = byte_object.getvalue()
```

I write this to Redis cache

```
context.redis.set(COMPLETE_GZIPPED_CACHE, final_data)
```

I have an API handler where I want to return the gzipped data

```
    cache_list = redis.get(COMPLETE_GZIPPED_CACHE)
    self.finish(
        {
            "status": True,
            "cache_list": cache_list,
            "updated_at": datetime.datetime.now(),
        }
    )
```

The problem is I'm getting the below error

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Do i need to decode the bytes first back to string before returning to the frontend? ideally i would like the frontend to handle the decoding

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please provide which Redis client is used, but generally - you should be able to reconfigure it (or use a different method) to not use JSON serialization on that byte array, but just store/retrieve it "as is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out from other posts - wrote a function like this and opted to use `zlib`

```
def convert_to_gzip_format(dict):
    stringified_object = json.dumps(dict).encode("utf-8")
    compressed_file = zlib.compress(stringified_object)

    base64_string = base64.b64encode(compressed_file).decode("ascii")
    return base64_string
```

This saves it as an ascii string to redis. I then use `pako.js` in the frontend to decode the above into a readable string.